# can't test app on my iPhone after updating to 7.1

Tags: xcode, organizer

I have the latest Mac OS on my MAC 10.9.1. The latest Xcode version 5.0.2 and now I've updated to the beta version 7.1, but for some reason when I'm trying to test an app on my device i'm receiving this message:

> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS
>   version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
>   run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

So while checking in the `Xcode >> window >> organiser`, I notice my device become orange instead of green and having this message:

> The version of iOS on “Johnny's iPhone” is not supported by this
>   installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of
>   the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK;
>   which is available

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Is it the latest version of the SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade Xcode to latest 5.1 Beta 4 and also be running the latest Beta of 7.1 on your device. The 7.1 iOS Betas are not compatible with versions of Xcode prior to 5.1.